# How to COUNT users from another table with a JOIN in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, count

I have a 3 tables, I have joined 2 tables so that I get something this, lets call it Table1
This has duplicates sometimes as information was filled out wrong

| company_id | company_name | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  |
| 1 | A | X |
| 2 | B | Y |
| 3 | C1 | Z |
| 3 | C | Z |

Now I also have another table with users for each company, call it Table2

| company_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | wwdw |
| 2 | dfsg |
| 2 | dasd |
| 3 | sfad |
| 3 | sadd |

I want to join these tables and get a table that counts the users in each company_id (repeats for duplicates)

| company_id | company_name | location | user_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  | 1 |
| 1 | A | X | 1 |
| 2 | B | Y | 2 |
| 3 | C1 | Z | 2 |
| 3 | C | Z | 2 |

Any idea how to do this?

This is my first join for table 1, how would I edit this to get the final table

```
SELECT clg.company_id, clg.name, c.location_address FROM clg, c

WHERE clg.company_id = c.id
```

Comment: You forgot the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a subquery, not a `JOIN`:

```
select t1.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.company_id = t1.company_id
       ) as num_users;
from table1 t1;
```

If you have your heart set on `JOIN`, then aggregate before joining:

```
select t1.*, t2.num_users
from table1 t1 join
     (select company_id, count(*) as num_users
      from table2 t2
      group by company_id
     ) t2
     on t1.company_id= t2.company_id;
```